# In bootstrap modal body Login button gets down when right aligned

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

in bootstrap modal body the Login button gets down, when i use **pull-right** class. how can i position this button within the bootstrap modal body. here is the following [image]

the code:

```
<div id="usersLog" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">You are most Welcome to Join Our Family</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usr">User Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn pull-right">Clear</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Login</button>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Also in chrome the all background template gets shifted right when i call this modal. Please share this solution also.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.pull-right` (and `.pull-left`) use `float`, which takes the element out of the normal flow of the page.  That's not what you want here.

In this simple case all you need is a new block element with content left aligned:

```
<div class="text-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Clear</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Login</button>
</div>
```

> the all background template gets shifted right

I do not see this - it must be something in your own CSS?  Or maybe it is `.pull-right` doing it?

Comment: its working....it shifted when the page contains enough information....actually due to vast information when scroll bar comes at right ....then the background shifted right. but in Mozilla its alright